# One String Input: Ints seperated by ' ' need to print array in reverse

Tags: python, arrays, io, reverse

So I am being passed one string of ints. The first denotes the amount of ints i am being passed, the rest are the ints that are being passed.

example of string i'm being passed : 4 1 2 3 4
expected output: 4 3 2 1

Here is what I wrote

```
import sys

n = int(raw_input().strip())
arr = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))

arr.reverse()
print(arr)
```

it works if I type 4 then enter, then 1 2 3 4, but it doesnt work if i type 4 1 2 3 4 then press enter I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   *File name removed by me* line 4, in <module>
n = int(raw_input().strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 1 2 3 4'
```

I understand the error... it is expecting a single base 10 number for n = int(raw_input().strip()) not a string of numbers separated by spaces. I have tried to alter my code to almost negate the first number entirely... its not even necessary I don't think as far as python goes. Can anyone help? I feel like I'm one small tweak away.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried to alter my code to almost negate the first number entirely... its not even necessary I don't think as far as python goes.

You are right, you can slice the list from 2nd element to last, ignoring the first element.

```
arr = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' ')[1:])
```

Comment: Yes.   But, note the line with the first `raw_input` call will have to be removed too

Comment: Thanks man!! I really appreciate it. That is a really cool feature I didn't even know existed in python. You can split a string, and then decide what index you want to start from... I am assuming you can add an end condition as well! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lists and loops as below too:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")
values = string.split(" ")
reverse = list()

for i in range(len(values)-1, 0, -1):
    reverse.append(values[i])

for item in reverse:
    print (item,end=" ")
```

Works as below:

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:/Python 3.5/test.py 
Enter a string: 3 2 3 5
5 3 2 
>>>
```

As the `n` is not necessary in your program, you can also modify your program and remove the error line as below:

```
import sys

arr = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))

arr.reverse()
arr = arr[:-1]
print(arr)
```

Its output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
4 0 1 2 3
[3, 2, 1, 0]
>>>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you my friend!

Comment: @CodyBentson You are welcome.  If my answer solved your issue, you can mark it as answer, by clicking on the tick mark at the left side of my answer. :)